# how can I permanently change db path in Mongodb?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

I tried `mongod --dbpath=/data` option to change the data directory location,  by executing this command   ***continously running in forground waiting for connection***

it  works on mongo CLI, But after I stop the `mongod --dbpath=/data` by CTRL +C,  mongo CLI refuse to Connect

Then After restarting mongod service, it's just normally use by default path in root directory.

Then I edited in /etc/mongodb.conf  db path parameter, after mongob serive can't start

```
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: 
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-07-15 19:36:47 IST; 5s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 5355 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited
 Main PID: 5355 (code=exited, status=2)
```

How do I make this permanent

**I change that new directory ownership to mongodb user
**I am using Ubuntu

Comment: Changing the `dbPath` in your configuration path (`/etc/mongod.conf` according to your service message would be the right place to persist the change. If you review the MongoDB log file (as per `systemLog.path` in the config file), there should be more context on the startup error. I would check that directory *and* file permissions are correct for the `dbPath` and log path. If you are still having issues, please edit your question to include details of the startup error from the MongoDB server log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed that problem, I am actually put **small case P in dbPath option**. 
Then I properly give **ownership that directory to mongodb** user account, It works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

change your `init.d/mongodb` script and make the following changes.I have used my own config ie. mongod1.conf. Make sure to change the ownership of the dbpath and log to **mongodb**

[image]